# Printing the label of a button when clicked

Tags: python, maya

So I'm trying to output the label of the button as it's pressed (Button label should replace the XXX in the print of the buttonNumber function). I do not know how to retrieve the label data from the button to output. Any thoughts? Thanks in advance

```
import maya.cmds as mc

def buttonNumber(*args):
    print 'Button XXX was pressed'

def openWindow():
    if mc.window('windowTest', ex=True):
        mc.deleteUI('windowTest', window=True)

    mc.window('windowTest', title='', s=True, resizeToFitChildren = True,)
    mc.rowColumnLayout(numberOfColumns = 3, columnWidth = [ (1, 150), (2, 150), (3, 150)])
    mc.button(label='1', command=buttonNumber)
    mc.button(label='2', command=buttonNumber)
    mc.button(label='3', command=buttonNumber)
    mc.button(label='4', command=buttonNumber)
    mc.button(label='5', command=buttonNumber)
    mc.button(label='6', command=buttonNumber)
    mc.button(label='7', command=buttonNumber)
    mc.button(label='8', command=buttonNumber)
    mc.button(label='9', command=buttonNumber)
    mc.showWindow('windowTest')

openWindow()
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to read my other posts on stackoverflow about Partial (note that there is another method with Lambda)

I didn't test the code below (I don't have maya here but you will get the idea)

```
import maya.cmds as mc
from functools import partial

def buttonNumber(label, *args):
    print('Button {0:03d} was pressed'.format(label))

def openWindow():
    if mc.window('windowTest', ex=True):
        mc.deleteUI('windowTest', window=True)

    mc.window('windowTest', title='', s=True, resizeToFitChildren = True,)
    mc.rowColumnLayout(numberOfColumns = 3, columnWidth = [ (1, 150), (2, 150), (3, 150)])
    mc.button(label='1', command=partial(buttonNumber, 1))

    mc.showWindow('windowTest')

openWindow()
```

Answer (score 2):

As @DeWeeny says, you can bind a value to the button commands with a `functools.partial` object.  You could also do it with a function factory for this very simple application, or with a callable class that remembered a value for each instance.

### function factory

```
def make_callback(value):
    def inner_callback(_):
        print value, "was clicked"
return inner_callback


w = cmds.window()
c = cmds.columnLayout()
for n in range(9):
    cmds.button( label = str(n), command = make_callback(n))

cmds.showWindow(w)
```

The only subtlety there is that `inner_callback` has an unused argument (the `_`) which it needs because button callbacks always fire a useless parameter

### class

This is useful if the data is more complex or needs more calculation than in the function factory example

```
class NumberCallback(object):
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = 
def __call__(self, _):
    print self.id, "was clicked"

w = cmds.window()
c = cmds.columnLayout()
for n in range(9):
    cmds.button( label = str(n), command = NumberCallback(n))

cmds.showWindow(w)
```

This is functionally identical but if you had to do something with more complex behavior a class would make it tidy

### not lambda

You may find advice on the web to do it with a `lambda`.  For lots of applications that would be great -- but don't do it in a loop.  If you do this:

```
def clicked(num):
    print num, "was clicked"

w = cmds.window()
c = cmds.columnLayout()
for n in range(9):
    cmds.button( label = str(n), command = lambda p: clicked(n))

cmds.showWindow(w)
```

All the buttons will respond

```
8 was clicked
```

because the lambdas will all capture the last variable in the loop which is not what you want.

More details [here](http://theodox.github.io/2014/maya_callbacks_cheat_sheet).  And a maya-specific module for exactly this sort of thing [here](https://github.com/theodox/mGui)

Comment: The function factory is interresting. I didn't know it was possible but I think partial is more readable :d. Thanks for sharing !

Answer (score 1):

I did a little reminder on my blog some time ago, to be able to test all the different native Maya UI way of using commands with a fast way of testing them:

- classic maya string
- function as argument
- lambda
- **functools.partial**
- pymel.core.Callback

Each case is also given with examples with passing variables as arguments to those functions. Because sometimes you have to be able to.
Overall I totally recommend the use **functools.partial**, it gives only advantages over the others (if you forget about PySide).

[Maya UI types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0xPp.png)

```
def function(*args):
    print args
    cmds.textFieldGrp(text, edit=True, text=str(args))

variable = 'Variable'
width = [1, 250]
align = [1, 'left']
window = cmds.window(title='UI and commands arguments.')
cmds.columnLayout()

cmds.textFieldGrp(label="\"function()\"", changeCommand="function()", columnWidth=width, columnAlign=align)
cmds.textFieldGrp(label="function", changeCommand=function, columnWidth=width, columnAlign=align)
cmds.textFieldGrp(label="\"function(variable)\"", changeCommand="function(variable)", columnWidth=width, columnAlign=align)
cmds.textFieldGrp(label="lambda x: function(variable)", changeCommand=lambda x: function(variable), columnWidth=width, columnAlign=align)
cmds.separator(style="double", height=20)

import functools
cmds.textFieldGrp(changeCommand=functools.partial(function), label='functools.partial(function)', columnWidth=width, columnAlign=align)
cmds.textFieldGrp(changeCommand=functools.partial(function, variable), label='functools.partial(function, variable)', columnWidth=width, columnAlign=align)
cmds.separator(style="single", height=20)

import pymel.core
cmds.textFieldGrp(changeCommand=pymel.core.Callback(function), label='pymel.core.Callback(function)', columnWidth=width, columnAlign=align)
cmds.textFieldGrp(changeCommand=pymel.core.CallbackWithArgs(function), label='pymel.core.CallbackWithArgs(function)', columnWidth=width, columnAlign=align)
cmds.textFieldGrp(changeCommand=pymel.core.CallbackWithArgs(function, variable), label='pymel.core.CallbackWithArgs(function, variable)', columnWidth=width, columnAlign=align)

cmds.separator(style="single", height=20)
text = cmds.textFieldGrp(label='RESULT: ', text='', width=500)
cmds.showWindow()
```

---

## When using a class

Because it was not made with the use of class in mind, some ways does not work at all when you are in a class.

```
class MayaUI():
    def __init__(self):
        self.variable = 'Variable'
        self.width = [1, 250]
        self.align = [1, 'left']
        self.window = cmds.window(title='UI and commands arguments.')
        cmds.columnLayout()

        cmds.textFieldGrp(label="\"self.function()\"", changeCommand="self.function()", columnWidth=self.width, columnAlign=self.align)
        cmds.textFieldGrp(label="self.function", changeCommand=self.function, columnWidth=self.width, columnAlign=self.align)
        cmds.textFieldGrp(label="\"self.function(self.variable)\"", changeCommand="self.function(self.variable)", columnWidth=self.width, columnAlign=self.align)
        cmds.textFieldGrp(label="lambda x: self.function(self.variable)", changeCommand=lambda x: self.function(self.variable), columnWidth=self.width, columnAlign=self.align)
        cmds.separator(style="double", height=20)

        import functools
        cmds.textFieldGrp(changeCommand=functools.partial(self.function), label='functools.partial(self.function)', columnWidth=self.width, columnAlign=self.align)
        cmds.textFieldGrp(changeCommand=functools.partial(self.function, self.variable), label='functools.partial(self.function, self.variable)', columnWidth=self.width, columnAlign=self.align)
        cmds.separator(style="single", height=20)

        import pymel.core
        cmds.textFieldGrp(changeCommand=pymel.core.Callback(self.function), label='pymel.core.Callback(self.function)', columnWidth=self.width, columnAlign=self.align)
        cmds.textFieldGrp(changeCommand=pymel.core.CallbackWithArgs(self.function), label='pymel.core.CallbackWithArgs(self.function)', columnWidth=self.width, columnAlign=self.align)
        cmds.textFieldGrp(changeCommand=pymel.core.CallbackWithArgs(self.function, self.variable), label='pymel.core.CallbackWithArgs(self.function, self.variable)', columnWidth=self.width, columnAlign=self.align)

        # A bit more complicated
        _map = {'textFieldGrp': lambda arg:cmds.textFieldGrp(arg, query=True, text=True)}
        _com = lambda *args:args[0](self.variable, _map[args[1]](args[2]))
        cmds.textFieldGrp('textfieldName', changeCommand=pymel.core.Callback(_com, self.function, 'textFieldGrp', 'textfieldName'), label="pymel.core.Callback(_com, self.function, 'textFieldGrp', 'textfieldName') + lambdas", columnWidth=self.width, columnAlign=self.align)

        cmds.separator(style="single", height=20)
        self.text = cmds.textFieldGrp(label='RESULT: ', text='', width=500)
        cmds.showWindow()

    def function(self, *args):
        print args
        cmds.textFieldGrp(self.text, edit=True, text=str(args))

MayaUI()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my code that does what you need.

Instead of hard-coding the argument of the label of each button to pass to the function at button creation time, I pass the object name of the button into the function. This way, all attributes of the button (including the label) can be queried at any point.

To show this I made a randomise function that generates random alphanumeric strings and assigns them to the button labels.

It'll entertain you for 30 seconds. Try it!

[image: screenshot 1]

```
import maya.cmds as mc
import random, string
from functools import partial

def randomButtonTest():
    buttonsList = []
    numButtons = 5
    winName = 'randomButtonWin'
    winWidth = 250
    statusTfgName = 'myStatusTfg'
    buttonLabelLength = 10

    def generateRandomLabel(myLength):
        # generates a random string of characters of myLength
        randomCandidatesList = list(string.ascii_letters + string.digits)
        random.shuffle(randomCandidatesList)
        randomCandidatesStr = ''.join(randomCandidatesList)
        return ''.join([randomCandidatesStr[random.randint(0,len(randomCandidatesStr)-1)] for x in range(myLength)])

    def reportButtonLabel(whichButton, *args):
        buttonLabel = mc.button(whichButton, q=True, label=True)
        print 'reportButtonLabel: clicked - %s' % buttonLabel
        mc.textFieldGrp(statusTfgName, e=True, text=buttonLabel)
        return

    def randomiseButtonClicked(*args):
        mc.textFieldGrp(statusTfgName, e=True, text='')
        for thisButton in buttonsList:
            currentLabel = mc.button(thisButton, q=True, label=True)
            newLabel = '%s: %s' %(currentLabel.split(':')[0], generateRandomLabel(buttonLabelLength))
            mc.button(thisButton, e=True, label=newLabel)
        return

    # build UI
    if mc.window(winName, exists=True):
        mc.deleteUI(winName)
    mc.window(winName, title='Randon Button Labels', w=winWidth )
    mc.columnLayout(w=winWidth)

    # create numButtons number of buttons
    for buttonId in range(numButtons):
        buttonsList.append(mc.button(label='button %i:'%buttonId, w=winWidth ))
        mc.button(buttonsList[-1], e=True, command=partial(reportButtonLabel, buttonsList[-1]))
    mc.text(label='')
    mc.textFieldGrp(statusTfgName, label='Button clicked', w=winWidth, columnWidth2=[winWidth*0.3, winWidth*0.65])
    mc.text(label='')
    mc.button('Randomise labels', w=winWidth, command=randomiseButtonClicked)

    randomiseButtonClicked()
    mc.window(winName, e=True, w=winWidth, h=150, resizeToFitChildren=True)
    mc.showWindow(winName)

randomButtonTest()
```